# I've never eaten sushi before or until now

Tags: present-perfect

scenario 1: I'm eating sushi.

scenario 2: I'll eat sushi in a couple of minutes.

I say to my friends who sit besides me,

> I've never eaten sushi before.

> I've never eaten sushi until now.

Do both sentences imply a change that I'm making: I'm eating sushi now or I'll eat sushi very soon?

Answer (score 3):

"I've never eaten sushi before" is the most idiomatic. We would say it in **either** scenario.

We **might** say "I've never eaten sushi until now," but in scenario 2 it sounds somewhat unnatural.